# XSLT 2.0 XPATH expression with variable

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm working on a Java based xsl-transformation (XSLT 2.0, could also be XSLT 3.0 if there is a free processor for java) with different input xml files. one input file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
    <MyElement>
        <CHILD>A</CHILD>
        <CHILDBEZ>ABEZ</CHILDBEZ>
        <NotInteresting></NotInteresting>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <CHILD>B</CHILD>
        <CHILDBEZ>BBEZ</CHILDBEZ>
        <NotInteresting2></NotInteresting2>
    </MyElement>
</TEST>
```

I want to copy all elements but "NotInteresting" and rename the two nodes CHILD and CHILDBEZ based on two parameters that I get from a mapping file:

- the xpath expression that tells me where the text of interest is placed (in this case: TEST/MyFirstElement/CHILD and TEST/MyFirstElement/CHILDBEZ)
- and the names of the elements what they should have in the output file (in this case: childName and childBez)

the mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element root="TEST">
    <childName>TEST/MyElement/CHILD</childName>
    <childBez>TEST/MyElement/CHILDBEZ</childBez>
</element>
```

desired output:

```
<TEST>
    <MyElement>
        <childName>A</childName>
        <childBez>ABEZ</childBez>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <childName>B</childName>
        <childBez>BBEZ</childBez>
    </MyElement>
</TEST>
```

what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0 "
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.apoverlag.at"
    xmlns:apo="http://www.apoverlag.at">

    <xsl:variable name="vars" select="document('mapping.xml')"/>
    <xsl:param name="src" />
     <xsl:variable name="path" xpath-default-namespace="" select="$src/path"/> <!-- = TEST/*-->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$path">
            <xsl:call-template name="buildNode">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="current()"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="buildNode">
        <xsl:param name="currentNode" />
        <xsl:element name="test">
            <xsl:for-each select="$vars/element/@root">
                <xsl:for-each select="$vars/element/*">
                    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}"> <xsl:value-of select="concat($currentNode,'/',current())" /> 
                        </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

My problem is that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($currentNode,'/',current())" />
```

gives me "/TEST/MyFirstElement/CHILD" when I try it hardcoded with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentNode/CHILD" />
```

I receive my desired output. Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: "*I want to copy all elements but "NotInteresting"*"  What exactly determines this? In your example, both `NotInteresting` and `NotInteresting2` are removed - by what criteria?

Comment: because these 2 elements are not part of the mapping file. I only wnat to copy elements that have a definition.

Comment: "*these 2 elements are not part of the mapping file.*" The elements `TEST` and `MyElement` are also not part of the mapping file, yet you do want them copied.

Comment: I want to copy elements that are part of the mapping file plus the parent and the root element because I need this structure.

Comment: This makes it much more complicated, because each element needs to test not only its own path against the mapping file, but also the paths of all its descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a radically different approach. To simplify, I have used a mapping document with **full** paths (starting with the `/`  root node):

**mapping xml**

```
<element root="TEST">
    <childName>/TEST/MyElement/CHILD</childName>
    <childBez>/TEST/MyElement/CHILDBEZ</childBez>
</element>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="mapping" select="document('mapping.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="map" match="*" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="parent-path"/>
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="concat($parent-path, '/', name())" />
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="key('map', $path, $mapping)" />
    <xsl:element name="{if ($replacement) then name($replacement) else name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="original" select="not($replacement)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass">
            <xsl:with-param name="parent-path" select="$path"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@original='true' and not(descendant::*/@original='false')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result, when applied to the provided input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
   <MyElement>
      <childName>A</childName>
      <childBez>ABEZ</childBez>
   </MyElement>
   <MyElement>
      <childName>B</childName>
      <childBez>BBEZ</childBez>
   </MyElement>
</TEST>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. It's much better to save the whole xpath expression to the mapping file.