# XSLT 2.0 dynamic XPATH expression

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have one XML file that I need to transform based on a mapping file with XSLT 2.0. I'm using the Saxon HE processor.

My mapping file:

```
<element root="TEST">
    <childName condition="/TEST/MyElement/CHILD[text()='B']>/TEST/MyElement/CHILD</childName>
    <childBez condition="/TEST/MyElement/CHILD[text()='B']>/TEST/MyElement/CHILDBEZ</childBez>
</element>
```

I have to copy the elements  CHILD and CHILDBEZ plus the parent and the root elements when the text of CHILD equals B. 
So with this Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
    <MyElement>
        <CHILD>A</CHILD>
        <CHILDBEZ>ABEZ</CHILDBEZ>
        <NotInteresting></NotInteresting>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <CHILD>B</CHILD>
        <CHILDBEZ>BBEZ</CHILDBEZ>
        <NotInteresting2></NotInteresting2>
    </MyElement>
</TEST>
```

the desired output:

```
<TEST>
    <MyElement>
        <childName>B</childName>
        <childBez>BBEZ</childBez>
    </MyElement>
</TEST>
```

what I have so far (based on this solution [XSLT 2.0 XPATH expression with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842374/xslt-2-0-xpath-expression-with-variable/34903078?noredirect=1#comment57550249_34903078)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="mapping" select="document('mapping.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="map" match="*" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="parent-path" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="concat($parent-path, '/', name())"/>
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="key('map', $path, $mapping)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="condition" select="key('map', $path, $mapping)/@condition"/>        
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$condition!= ''">
            <!-- if there is a condition defined in the mapping file, check for it -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{if ($replacement) then name($replacement) else name()}">
                <xsl:attribute name="original" select="not($replacement)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass">
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent-path" select="$path" tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@original='true' and not(descendant::*/@original='false')]"/>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the problem is that it's impossible to evaluate dynamic XPATH expressions with XSLT 2.0. Does anyone knows a workaround for that? Plus I have a problem with the mapping file. When there is only one element in it, it's not working at all.

Comment: Why do you need that mapping file? Can't you just write a stylesheet with templates and appropriate match patterns? What do you gain by using that mapping format and wanting to use dynamic XPath evaluation? Have you considered using one XSLT to generate another XSLT from your mapping to do the job?

Comment: I need a mapping file because I have different Input XML Files from different providers and I thought to make a mapping file once for all input files would be a good and readable solution. But I have to think about other solutions as well. Using XSLT to generate another XSLT sounds good I will try this one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dynamic XPath evaluation isn't an option in your chosen processor, then generating an XSLT stylesheet is often a good alternative. In fact, it's often a good alternative anyway.

One way of thinking about this is that your mapping file is actually a program written in a very simple transformation language. There are two ways of executing this program: you can write an interpreter (dynamic XPath evaluation), or you can write a compiler (XSLT stylesheet generation). Both work well.